# Error: trying to install pip OSX Lion

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion

I've installed the latest version of python and from "mistake" to say so i've deleted the `2.7 python` from system. Now when i'm trying to install `pip` or `easy_install` i receive the errors below:

```
$ pip install Selenium
python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory.
```

Later edit: seems pip do not supports python 3 and up. I can use easy_install now, after I've took the steps described over here http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx .

Thank you!

Comment: Seems as if you've removed the system wide python: http://www.python.org/getit/mac/ - follow this to reinstall it.

Comment: It's necessarily to have the wide python installed ? Cannot use the 3.3 as wide ?

Answer (score 0):

You have apparently deleted Python from your computer.

Reinstall OSX to restore it with other means, like mentioned in the comments.

In the future, do not do system-wide Python package installations:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/